# Referência de variáveis no JavaScript

Tags: javascript, referência

Para gerar a seguinte matriz:

```
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
```

Considerem o seguinte código para construção de uma matriz com linhas iguais:

```
var linha = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var matriz = [linha, linha, linha ];
matriz[3] = linha ;      // outra alternativa
matriz.push(linha);      // mais outro modo
```

Parece lógico usar esse código para gerar a matriz. Mas temos um porém, estamos adicionando elementos **por referência** no Array `matriz`.

Se tentarmos

```
matriz[0].push();       // retirar o elemento na posição A[0][4]
matriz[1][1] = 10;      // alterarmos A[1][1] de 2 para 10
```

replicamos as alterações para todas as linhas.

Gostaria que me falassem sobre esse comportamento do JavaScript:

- Os problemas que o uso descuidado pode implicar, e
- Qual o modo mais simples e aceitável de criar essa matriz e fazer essas alterações nela.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se você quer alterar independentemente os valores, precisa de algo deste tipo:

```js
var linha = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var matriz = [];

for( var i = 0; i<5; i++ ) {
   matriz.push( linha.slice() );
}

//testando alteração:
matriz[2][2] = 999;

for( var i = 0; i<5; i++ ) {
  body_log( 'matriz[' + i + ']:' + matriz[i] );
}


// só pra nao precisar de console:
function body_log(msg) {
  document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + '<p>' + msg + '</p>';
}
```

O que está acontecendo aqui é que o `.slice()` é uma das formas de produzir um clone de um *array*, e não uma nova referência.

Como você mesmo mencionou, quando alguém faz `umaVariavel = umArray` em JS, está simplesmente dizendo que `umaVariavel` aponta para o mesmo espaço na memória que `umArray`, e a consequência é que quando você acessa qualquer uma das duas coisas, está vendo os mesmos dados. Qualquer alteração feita, seja por um nome ou outro, será refletida ao acessá-los.

A mesma coisa acontece quando você aponta um sub-índice de *array* para outro array. Aquele sub-índice estará apontando para o mesmo espaço que a variável original.

### Comportamento em recursividade

O exemplo a seguir é pra confundir uns e preocupar outros. Tente endender o que acontece quando você além de usar *arrays* por referência, faz a referência dentro da própria *array*:

```js
var matriz = [];
matriz.push( [00, 01, 02,     03, 04, 05] );
matriz.push( [10, 11, 12,     13, 14, 15] );
matriz.push( [20, 21, 22,     23, 24, 25] );
matriz.push( [30, 31, 32, matriz, 34, 35] );
matriz.push( [40, 41, 42,     43, 44, 45] );
matriz.push( [50, 51, 52,     53, 54, 55] );

body_log( 'matriz[1][1]      <br>' + matriz[1][1] );
body_log( 'matriz[2][2]      <br>' + matriz[2][2] );
body_log( 'matriz[3][3]      <br>' + matriz[3][3] );
body_log( 'matriz[3][3][2]   <br>' + matriz[3][3][2] );
body_log( 'matriz[3][3][1][2]<br>' + matriz[3][3][1][2] );

// alterando:
matriz[3][3][1][2] = 999;
body_log( 'matriz[3][3][1][2] = 999<br>');
body_log( 'resultado:<br>' + matriz );

matriz[0][0] = matriz[3];
matriz[3][3][0][0][3][4] = "que?";

body_log( 'matriz[0][0] = matriz[3] e matriz[3][3][0][0][3][4] = "que?"' );
body_log( 'resultado:<br>' + matriz );

function body_log(msg) { document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + '<p>' + msg + '</p>'; }
```

Percebe como a *array* consegue acessar a si própria por meio de um dos seus membros? Espero que você esteja vendo este exemplo num *browser* bem implementado, que simplesmente esconda o membro 3,3 da *array*, senão ele vai entrar em colapso.

Note que ao alterarmos o membro [3][3][1][2] da matriz estamos na verdade alterando o membro [1][2], pois o membro [3][3] é a própria *array*.

Pra "piorar", acrescentei na demonstração uma alteração transformando o ítem [0][0] na linha 3 da matriz, e alterando um dos seus membros, e alterando a linha 4 inteira para uma string, por meio de três recursões. Pra quem gosta de jogar **[Portal](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TluRVBhmf8w)**, fica fácil entender.

Imagine num caso real o tipo de confusão que dá pra fazer quando não se sabe a diferença entre um valor verdadeiro e uma mera referência.

Comment: Essa sua função `body_log` devia ser default no Stack Snippets.

Comment: Sempre pensei nisso, mesmo no JSFiddle :)

Comment: Bom lembrar que o `slice` não elimina a referência quando algum elemento do Array for um Objeto. :)